# Why isn't css :active class working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a set of buttons which have 3 CSS states attached: default, `:hover` and `:active`.
Both the default and `:hover` states display correctly, but the `:active` state is ignored in IE7.

I'm really not feeling a JavaScript fix and would like to avoid this if at all possible.

Answer (score 4):

`:hover` works in IE 7. `:active` works in IE 7 only if applied to an `<a/>` element.

See the compatibility list here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 2):

[IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) should do the trick. Just use:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Subset of selectors it handles:

```
parent > child
adjacent + sibling
adjacent ~ sibling
.multiple.classes
:hover  Now applies to all elements
:first-child
```

It also fixes CSS properties, as well as png transparency. In addition, it is lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the classes on a link element? If I remember correctly, IE7 doesn't recognize states such as hover and active on anything that is not a link.